# Can very flat surfaces radiate heat in a mostly-perpendicular manner?

Tags: quantum-optics, infrared-radiation

What determines the direction (i.e. angle) at which an emitted photon travels? Are very flat surfaces more spatially-coherent (i.e. the photons travel in a parallel manner, akin to a laser beam) or perhaps can be made so? Or is the thermal radiation completely scattered?

Answer (score 3):

> Are very flat surfaces more spatially-coherent

Actually, emissive directionality can be increased by introducing topography. I include some content from Modest's *Radiative Heat Transfer*:

"*A spectral surface whose emittance is the same for all directions is called a diffuse emitter, or a Lambert surface...*

*No real surface can be a diffuse emitter since electromagnetic wave theory predicts a zero emittance at θ = π/2 for all materials...*

[However,] *little energy is emitted into grazing
directions...*

[Thus, d]*iffuse emission is nearly always an acceptable
simplification* [for flat surfaces] *...*":

[image]

[image]

"*Surfaces can be made directionally selective by mechanically altering the surface finish on a microscale
(microgrooves) or macroscale.*

*For example, large V-grooves (large compared with the wavelengths of radiation)
tend to reflect incoming radiation several times for near-normal incidence, as indicated in Fig. 3.36 ... for an opening angle of γ = 30°, each time absorbing a fraction of the beam. The number of
reflections decreases with increasing incidence angle, down to a single reflection for incidence angles θ > 90° −γ
(or 60° in the case of Fig. 3.36).*

[T]*his type of surface has a significantly higher
normal emittance, which is important for collection of solar irradiation, than hemispherical emittance, which
governs emission losses.*"

[image]

See that text for more discussion and references.

Comment: That's interesting. So basically such a surface tends to resorb more of the radiation emitted from within the grooves when the angle of emissivity of a particular photon is great enough (compared to normal) to induce interaction(s) with the walls of the grooves?

Comment: I would check the original papers to see how the researchers articulated their broad strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The thermal emission of an ideal black body radiator is diffuse and follows the same [Lambert law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance) as diffuse reflection. There is no coherence at all. For a non-ideal emitter you have to take into account the complex refractive index via the emissivity.